# 40 seconds strange sql performance puzzle

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a query to update my user's field like the following:

```
UPDATE Members SET abc = abc + 1 where Members.id in (
SELECT DISTINCT(memberId) FROM Events WHERE Events.createdAt > "2017-08-06 13:10:00";
```

Shockingly, with about 500 members, this query runs for 40 seconds...

so the break down:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(memberId) FROM Events WHERE Events.createdAt > "2017-08-06 13:10:00"
```

runs for 0.1s and there're only 39 rows matched.

The total # of Members is only ~500. I don't understand why this can take that long... Am I missing something?

I'm running on RDS with mysql 5.6

Comment: How large is the `Events` table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, the Events table is about 150k rows

Comment: You left out the most critical part of your question.  Check Gordon's answer +1.

Comment: Always copy and paste your code here, don't retype as errors will invariably crop up, often to the point where the meaning of the question will get lost. Like the paren that closes the opening paren after `IN`

Comment: @BobKaufman Sorry about that. Since I had to leave some business details. But suggestion taken :)

Answer (score 6):

Try replacing with `exists`:

```
UPDATE Members m
    SET abc = abc + 1 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM events e
                  WHERE e.memberId = m.id AND
                        e.createdAt > '2017-08-06 13:10:00'
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `events(memberId, createdAt)`.

My guess is that MySQL runs the subquery once for every row in `Members`.  This is consistent with your timing -- ~0.1 seconds * ~500 rows is about 50 seconds, not that far off of 40 seconds.

For `SELECT`s, this was fixed several versions ago.  Perhaps this issue still exists in non-`SELECT` queries.

You can also write this as:

```
UPDATE Members m JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT e.memberId
        FROM events e
        WHERE e.createdAt > '2017-08-06 13:10:00'
       ) e
       ON e.memberId = m.id
    SET abc = abc + 1 ;
```

Whether this is faster than the `exists` version, depends on characteristics of your data.  Without the suggested index, this is likely to be faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. Hmm.. this is surprising since I came from a background with little DB experience. However from a point of view of big O notation, this shall be something like O(M*N), where M is number of rows in Member, N is number of rows for Events. It looks like your second suggestion is identical in terms of computational complexity.... but it's waaaay faster (0.13s without index anything). I'd love to hear more why that's the case.

Comment: @eddie.xie . . . The query should not be O(M*N) -- although your version is because MySQL runs the subquery for each row in `m`.  The first version is something like O(M * log(N)) -- the log(N) is the time for the index lookup.  The second is something like O(M^2 + N log(N)).  The M^2 is for the join (really much better than that because `e` is much smaller than `m`.  The N log(N) is for the aggregation (i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT`).

Comment: Hmm... I guess I started to understand why. Is it because if you do a join, then the table e is scanned once, and then a join with m is performed. So the complexity is O(m*logm) for sorting m, and O(n*logn) for sorting e, and then merge them together? then it's << O(m*n)?

Comment: One last followup question since you seem to know a great deal about the internal implementation :) why isn't the inner select results stored? This seems to be an obvious (and eazy?) speed boosting trick, just like if you have a nested loop, you want to cache the inner loop result if you can, right? I bet smart people in MySQL team thought of this already

Comment: @eddie.xie . . . They have and they have fixed the problem at least for `select`s.  In general, they recommend using joins for this sort of thing.